# Why do bicycle wheels rotate when I lift it upstairs?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, everyday-life

When I go upstairs with my bike I notice that its wheels start to rotate, or they spin faster or slower if they have initial speed. I tried to move the front wheel with acceleration in different directions, roll and yaw it with no initial rotation - no angular momentum, and indeed, it spun in one direction, and in another if I did everything in the opposite directions. What is the reason for that?

Comment: Does the same thing happen if you just lift the bike slightly off the ground and do nothing else with it?

Comment: I will experiment tomorrow, but one thing is that the wheels may be off balance.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft yes, I've also tried to lift another bike and seen the front wheel spinning up during the acceleration and coming to a halt when I stopped the bike, as if the change of linear momentum leaded to the change of angular momentum.